# PHP include on 2 websites: one work, one not

Tags: javascript, lightbox2

on 2 websites I have included the `lightbox2-code` but on one it works, on the other not and I can't figure out the difference. on the not working site I get the error `typeerror $ is not a function ... lightbox.js (78,5)`

Comment: Include jQuery before all your scripts and After that define $ variable for jQuery functions.

Comment: There's not enough here for us to help. We can only speculate. Please provide more detail about both  applications.

Answer (score 0):

Lightbox2 requires jQuery. Make sure it is loaded ahead of the Lightbox script, or use the `lightbox-plus-jquery.js` file if you are not currently loading jQuery on your page. This file is located in the `dist/js/` folder of the Lightbox2 package.

Here is the relevant snippet form the official docs:

> Make sure jQuery, which is required by Lightbox, is also loaded.
>
> - If you already use jQuery on your page, make sure it is loaded before lightbox.js. jQuery 1.7 or greater is required.
> - If you are not currently using jQuery, I've created a packaged file that includes both Lightbox and jQuery. Include
>     dist/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.js instead of lightbox.js.